# random_shuffle() is not shuffling anything C++

Tags: c++, random

I am learning C++ and the book I am using uses random.shufle() in the code for a simple High Scores Program, I am typing the code verbatim but it is not working...
Whenever I run the program everything works except for the random_shuffle() portion. I have seeded it using srand(static_cast(time(0)));
 Here is the code:

```
//High Scores
//Demonstrates algorthms

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator iter;

    cout << "creating a list of scores.";
    vector<int> scores;
    scores.push_back(1500);
    scores.push_back(3500);
    scores.push_back(7500);

    cout << "\nHigh Scores:\n";
    for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nFinding a score.";
    int score;
    cout << "\nEnter a score to find: ";
    cin >> score;
    iter = find(scores.begin(), scores.end(), score);
    if (iter != scores.end())
    {
        cout << "Score found.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Score not found\n";
    }

    cout << "\nRandomizing scores.";
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(scores.begin(), scores.end());
    cout << "\nHigh Scores:\n";
    for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nSorting scores.";
    sort(scores.begin(), scores.end());
    cout << "\nHigh Scores:\n";
    for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using the book "Beginning C++ Through Game Programming" fourth edition, by Michael Dawson

Comment: With only 3 elements, there are only 6 possible permutations. It's not all that unlikely that you could get the exact same permutation you started with, even with a fair random shuffle. Also the method by which `random_shuffle` (which is deprecated in C++14, removed in C++17, btw) gets its randomness is unspecified. So there's no guarantee that `srand` is having any effect on it.

Comment: @ifconfing random_shuffle is a standard library algorithm.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think the likely case is the latter since I’ve ran the program multiple times with the same results

Comment: @ifconfig it’s somewhat towards the end of the code

Comment: What happens if you shuffle it twice, or three times?

Comment: Add a few more elements to `scores` and see what happens

Comment: Note that `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17. Use `std::shuffle`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oh ok, thx